# Laptop monitor not detected, only external monitor works

Tags: windows, laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hardware-detection

This all started when I had my laptop connected to my TV via HDMI and changed the display setting to "Show only on 2". I then remember opening my laptop and the internal display wasn't working, but the external display did. It doesn't appear to be a hardware issue with the laptop screen itself as sometimes it'll randomly work, I've updated the integrated graphics (Intel UHD Graphics 620) and also the other one (Nvidia MX150).

That did seem to get it to work for a bit then I closed the laptop lid to put it to sleep and it went back to the same issue. Also up to date with all the most recent Windows updates (Windows 11, 10.0.22631), there's one new BIOS update on the Acer website but it's purely for security.

I've tried booting in safe mode and BIOS to reset to default settings, booting in safe mode seemed to get the screen to work once but it hasn't since. What worked most recently was to roll back the integrated graphics to basic display, delete all the monitors including hidden, and then update the graphics back to the most recent version whilst disconnecting and reconnecting the external monitor.

Sometimes this gets the monitor to turn back on, other times it just detects the monitor on device manager but the internal monitor is still off. When this happens on the display settings it shows both monitors with "Show only on 2" when I try to change it, it asks to keep or revert and after clicking "keep changes" the setting just reverts to "Show only on 2".

Additionally, I've deleted the below registry keys to no avail, even deleting the whole "GraphicsDrivers" and resetting the laptop with no difference. To me, it seems like the "Show only on 2" is the cause as it always reverts to this setting when it detects both monitors, but I don't know how to change this.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Connectivity
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\ScaleFactors
```

Comment: Leave your registry alone. Don't mess with it. When you need to fully reset your graphical system settings open the Device Manager, find your Display Adapter, and delete that and then restart your computer. Once drives are reinstalled you should be operating back in a default state.

Comment: Boot with a bootable USB Key with some OS and see if the internal display works.

Comment: I have tried deleting my integrated display adapter, not sure if deleting both makes a difference. That didn't work, on reboot the screen doesn't turn on if I disconnect the external one, I then have to reset it again with the external connected otherwise I have no display.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a USB large enough to try that atm, sounds like a good idea nonetheless. Will try sometime this week, thank you.

Comment: @awly9, " I do not have a USB large enough..." 8 GB is enough for a complete Ubuntu boot disk, and there are far smaller distros, e.g., Puppy Linux, 300 **MB**. The idea is not to *install* Linux, but to quickly make a bootable device to see if display works at all.

Comment: did you use  the hotkey to switch the displays?

Comment: @jsotola, Yes I tried that but as the internal display isn't detected there wasn't anything to switch between.

Comment: @John, Thanks for the suggestion John and DrMoishe Pippik, my USB is 8GB and had a few things on it but I cleared it and loaded Ubuntu which got the internal display working. Seems to be an issue with my OS then by looks of it. Assume I'll have to backup my laptop then restore Windows/fresh install?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your monitor is working (you verified with a separate test), then:

I suggest doing a complete backup, and then reinstall Windows.

This is likely your best choice in the circumstances.

If you are able to log in (not entirely certain from above), you can do this with the Windows ISO (Media Creation Link) or do a system reset.   Start, Settings, Update, Advanced, Recovery and choose Reset this PC.

With the latter, once you have your data, choose Keep Everything and see if that works.

If not, you need to do a completely fresh install of Windows as I suggested earlier here.

Be sure to update all Drivers and perhaps temporarily disable Nvidia.

Comment: Okay to update, I have done a complete backup and tried resetting keeping everything as you said. I tried this twice, once with external monitor connected, second time without, and both times it didn't detect the internal display. The second time, after turning it off, this morning it was working, however when I closed the laptop lid it stopped working again when opening. Today I have done a complete reset deleting everything with external disconnected, still didn't detect the screen. Again playing around with adapters recognised the screen, however it's still stuck on "Show only on 2".

Comment: To add, I did restore files and settings after complete reset as the screen wasn't working, so maybe that's why settings still bugged. Also didn't select "clean data" on reset and installed Windows locally

Comment: It may be an issue with your profile (standard reset does not fix this). So you may need a complete reinstall of Windows as suggested in the first part of my answer.

Comment: Okay thanks, I misunderstood your initial comment, I was assuming that clearing everything and downloading Windows from cloud was a fresh install haha. Will try a clean installation now, thank you.

Comment: So I done a clean installation booting from USB, done all the Windows updates and it still isn't detecting the internal monitor, only my external one which I had connected so I could see. It's now detecting the external one connected via HDMI as the Integrated Monitor.

Comment: You said a few posts back that your internal display was working with Ubuntu. Make sure you have updated all your Windows Drivers. That could be a cause - driver incompatibility with the monitor. Are you able to disable Nvidia and use integrated graphics?  That is what Ubuntu would have used.

Comment: I had quite a few optional updates, after updating Intel system and Processor port updates the screen started to work again. It even worked after closing and reopening the lid, however once I put it to sleep, upon opening it's stopped working again. This was the first time it worked after the complete reset, and when it stopped it was detected on Device Manager but on display settings, it was still stuck as "Show only on 2". After restarting it no longer detects the monitor at all again, sigh. My displays seem to be linked to integrated graphics rather than the Nvidia one, tried disabling both

Comment: Try Drivers as well.  There seems to be a software issue since the monitor started working again,

Comment: All the optional drivers for Windows are updated, regarding graphics drivers the Intel/integrated one was already updated to most recent. I've just updated the Nvidia one too, didn't make a difference, then when I disabled the Intel GPU and re-enabled it, it started to work until I disconnected the external monitor then it went black and since stopped again.